# How do you center image inside square aspect ratio and maintain responsiveness?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a product grid for a client and was faced with the issue of properly centering a dynamic thumbnail (sometimes square, portrait, or landscape) in a square aspect ratio and maintaining responsiveness.

I am currently doing the following but was wondering if there was a more clean css solution for centering an image (vertically/horizontally) inside of a div much like you would with a background image on a responsive div with `background-size: contain`.

```css
.thumbnails {
  margin: auto;
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 100% ;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.thumbnail__img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100% ;
  max-height: 100% ;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  left: 50% ;
  top: 50% ;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50% );
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x600/000/fff">
  </figure>

  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff">
  </figure>

  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff">
  </figure>
</div>
```

[Demo JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3xt3r_adam5/0f1uzwak/9/)

Comment: Hey, it looks like this is an answer, not a question. It's totally fine (and encouraged!) to post a question and then answer it yourself (preferably with a little explanation in the answer about what you have done). You should make this a question and then post an answer. It'll be closed otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `object-fit: contain;`.

This way there is no need to use transform and meddle with left/top.

```css
.thumbnails{
  width: 250px;
}

.thumbnail{
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.thumbnail__img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: block; // important since images have default inline-block property
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x600/000/fff">
  </figure>

  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff">
  </figure>

  <figure class="thumbnail">
    <img class="thumbnail__img" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 [browser support of object-fit is pretty great](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit); just be aware that IE11 has no support and some older browsers have a few limitations.

Comment: I tried this but there was no way to keep the thumbs responsive and maintain square aspect ratio.

Comment: In my previous snippet, I've explicitly specify `height: 250px` of `.thumbnail`. Now, I've updated the code to use `padding-bottom: 100%` as of your code.

Comment: Oh, that is really nice! Awesome! I'll use this and my solution as a fallback for IE11.